# Javascript Regex Substitution newline handling in browsers

Tags: javascript, regex, newline

I created a html textarea with a capability to add "[" and "]" at the beginning and end of whatever text has been entered within that.

My problem is, when I enter some multiline data into the textarea, the regex is handled differently in ff and ie.

Input:

```
Iam
learning
regex
```

Expected Output: (I get this in FF )

```
[Iam]
[learning]
[regex]
```

Output in IE:

```
[Iam
][]
[learning
][]
[regex]
```

The Regex code is here:

```
(textareaIDelement.value).replace(/(^)(.*)(\n{0,})($)/gm, "[" + "$2" +"]");
```

I added the `(\n{0,})` in the regex to match newlines.. but it doesn't have any effect..

Thanks

Comment: `{0,}` (zero or more repetitions) can be written as `*`, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE, the line separator in a textarea's `value` property is `\r\n`. In all other major browsers it's `\n`. A simple solution would be to normalize line separators into `\n` first. I've also simplified the regex:

```
textareaIDelement.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").replace(/^(.*)\n*$/gm, "[$1]");
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that Firefox is using a single `0x0A` (`\n`) as the line separator, whereas IE is using the Windows separator `0x0D 0x0A` (`\r\n`).

Depending on the exact semantics of the regex library, it's probably matching both of the WIndows characters independently as line separators, hence it detects the end of the line followed by a 0-character line.

(This isn't an actual answer per se, as I'm not massively familiar with exactly how JS processes regex metacharacters, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction.)