# Problems with regular expression (Javascript) in IE 8

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8

I am using the following regular expression in Javascript:

```
    comment_body_content = comment_body_content.replace(/(<span id="sc_start_commenttext-(\d+)"><\/span>)
[^]*?(<span id="sc_end_commenttext-\2"><\/span>)/, "$1$3");
```

I want to find in my HTML code this tag `<span id="sc_start_commenttext-330"></span>` (the number is always different) and the tag `<span id="sc_end_commenttext-330"></span>`. Then the text and HTML code between those tags should be  deleted and the rest should be given back:

Before:

```
<span id="sc_start_commenttext-330"></span>
Some Text and some <u>html</u> blabla
<span id="sc_end_commenttext-330"></span>
```

Returned value of comment_body_content:

```
<span id="sc_start_commenttext-330"></span>
<span id="sc_end_commenttext-330"></span>
```

This expression works in all current browsers, but the IE 8 returns a javascript error at the lines, where are "(\d+)" and \2.

Is there a solution for all browsers?

Alex

Comment: What's the specific error that you get?

Comment: I just edit my question, there was a mistake. the error is (translated from german): Invalid range in character set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `[^]*?` in your regex by `.*?`

in order to deal with line break you'd use : `[\s\S]*?`

Comment: Hm, its not working correctly in the current browsers. Not all characters between `<span id="sc_start_commenttext-330"></span>` and `<span id="sc_end_commenttext-330"></span>` were deleted. This could be also \n etc...

Comment: @user1711384: What kind of character isn't deleted?

Comment: it seems, that its only working when there is no line break in the text. when there is a line break, nothing is deleted...using `[^]*?` works with all characters, but not in IE 8

Comment: Yeah, good message: In current browsers its working and no errors in IE8. Bad message: not all characters are deleted in IE8. Maybe this could be a reason: In current browsers there is generated a <br>-tag, in IE 8 a <p>-tag for a new line...

Comment: @user1711384: Really strange! `[\s\S]*` stands for any character, it'll match `<br>` as well as `<p>` tags.

Comment: Maybe its a bug in IE - people have to live with that. Thank you!

Comment: Jep, good job ;)
This doesnt help for a solution, does it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679271/javascript-regex-substitution-newline-handling-in-browsers

Answer (score 3):

This will work.

```
.replace(/(<span id="sc_start_commenttext-(\d+)"><\/span>)[\S\s.]*?(<span id="sc_end_commenttext-\2"><\/span>)/, "$1$3")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Rx96/5/

Comment: Sorry guys, i just made a mistake, the return value was wrong. I just edited my question!

Comment: Updated the answer to match the new requirements :)

Comment: Thx bart - same answer from M42 (see at the bottom) - we have now the problem with the new line in IE 8 :-/

Comment: Added `[\S\s.]` to match whitespaces, newlines and any character. You can extend the characters between the braces.

Comment: Works in all browsers but not in IE8 seems to be a bug :(

Comment: I tried with IE10 in IE8 browser mode in every document mode. It worked. Friggin IE with all it's different version of the same version ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to process HTML with regular expressions.

This is likely more useful - I'm using jQuery

We have ways to find both start and end if necessary, but the HTML you provided will be handled by this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3y9aJ/)

```
var comments = {}
$("span[id^='sc_start_commenttext-']").each(function() {
   var idx = this.id.split("-")[1];    
   comments[idx]=$(this).get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue;
});
window.console && console.log(comments["330"])
```

Comment: Your are right, but the code is generated by CMS and its not valid, so jquery istn working there :(

Comment: What do you mean by "not valid" ?

Comment: Its not valid XHTML...but i will try your code, maybe its working.
Hm, i dont understand your code...where is sc_end_commenttext?